# Cancel the StripeSubscriptionservice

Tags: c#, .net-core, stripe-payments

Right now, I work as a member of the site to cancel membership. Just when I try to run through the test, it makes the mistake of saying it

> Stripe.StripeException: 'No such subscription: cus_CCKeYhNjyKTYTh'

[Here's how information is displayed by a user with this ID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMnaA.png)

```
var api = Settings.ConstName.StrinpAPIKey;//Get Stripe Key from Class.
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(api);
var customerSerive = new StripeCustomerService(api);
var subservice = new StripeSubscriptionService(api);

var stripeCustomerID = customerSerive.Get(members.User.CustomerId);//members i get the userCustomerId from DB.

subservice.Cancel(subscriptionId: check.CustomerId, cancelAtPeriodEnd: true);
```

So my question is how it may be that it will not let me do it? Do I need anything more for it to stop the membership of the customer?

i have a [check here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/dotnet#cancel_subscription):

It's 100% the same ID I have in the database* and i get the version from stripe 12.1.0

i have complete this:

```
var api = Settings.ConstName.StrinpAPIKey;
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(api);
var customerSerive = new StripeCustomerService(api);
var subservice = new StripeSubscriptionService(api);

var stripeCustomerID = customerSerive.Get(members.User.CustomerId);
var GetIdSubscriptions = stripeCustomerID.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault(i => i.CustomerId == check.CustomerId).Id;
```

Comment: Exception message is there is no subscription found by the id you provided! `cus_CCKeYhNjyKTYTh` looks like a Customer ID. You just need to provide the correct Subscription ID to cancel subscription!

Comment: @Zico i have complete this now. and i have update the code.

Comment: I mean you have to send the Subscription ID in this method `subservice.Cancel(subscription ID)`